# How do I get assets to work when exporting a jar? (Net Beans)

Tags: java, netbeans

I've just a finished a program which makes use of lots of audio and image files. These are included in the project in src in the folder audio and images respectively. When I reference them I use use:

```
ImageIO.read(aclass.class.getResource(images/animage.png));
```

for images (referencing images directly)

or

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(src/audio/audio.wav);
```

for audio (reference audio from the src file)

However, when I clean and build the project and then try and run it as a jar most of assets are gone. Some of the images remain but I lose all audio.

Is there a way I can make sure that all these assets get loaded when I just run the exported jar?

Answer (score 0):

to load the resources inside the jar file you have to use the YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream method. it will return an input stream. should be self explainatory